# Как отловить Гутенберг

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В связи с выходом редактора Гутенберг, который получил название блочного редактора в WordPress 5.0, часто возникает вопрос - как программно определить, какой редактор используется в настоящее время для редактирования поста в консоли сайта?

Comment: Вопрос не по этому вопросу, но всё же. Не подскажите адекватную документацию по разработке своих блоков для гутенберга?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev нет документации. Или какие-то обрывки. И это большая проблема

Comment: Жаль, хотел попробовать что-нибудь написать. В итоге бросил это дело. Примеры, которые нашёл в большинстве случаи не рабочие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариантов тут можеть быть несколько:

- WordPress 4.9, плагин Гутенберг не активен
- WordPress 4.9, плагин Гутенберг активен
- WordPress 5.0, включен блочный редактор по умолчанию
- WordPress 5.0, активен плагин Classic Editor
- WordPress 5.0, активен плагин Classic Editor, но в консоли в "Настройки > Написание" выбрана опция "Использовать по умолчанию редактор блоков..."

Все указанные выше варианты могут обработаны следующим кодом:

```
/**
 * Check if Block Editor is active.
 * Must only be used after plugins_loaded action is fired.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_active() {
    // Gutenberg plugin is installed and activated.
    $gutenberg = ! ( false === has_filter( 'replace_editor', 'gutenberg_init' ) );

    // Block editor since 5.0.
    $block_editor = version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '5.0-beta', '>' );

    if ( ! $gutenberg && ! $block_editor ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( is_classic_editor_plugin_active() ) {
        $editor_option       = get_option( 'classic-editor-replace' );
        $block_editor_active = array( 'no-replace', 'block' );

        return in_array( $editor_option, $block_editor_active, true );
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Check if Classic Editor plugin is active.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_classic_editor_plugin_active() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active' ) ) {
        include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
    }

    if ( is_plugin_active( 'classic-editor/classic-editor.php' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Код возвращает true, если блочный редактор включен тем или иным способом, или false - в случае классического редактора. Вызывать эту функцию надо не ранее, чем сработает событие plugins_loaded.

P.S. В связи с выходом версии 1.2 плагина Classic Editor, код пришлось обновить, поскольку опция `classic-editor-replace` теперь принимает значения не `replace` и `no-replace`, а `classic` и `block`.